# USB CDC Bulk IN Endpoint Freeze

Tags: usb, cdc, lpc

I am using LPC2368 to communicate with PC using USB CDC.
When PC sends the command to LPC over Bulk Out End Point 2,LPC2368 recives 4104 bytes from UART which is sent to PC over USB CDC Bulk IN Endpoint 2.

At PC,this data is considered to be coming form virtual com port,enabling me to see the data (sent to PC) over hypertermial.

There are some commands to which response is less than 64bytes.

After sending command to get these 4104bytes,the 4014 bytes are successfully received from UART and sent in for loop(for in bulk transmission only 64 bytes can be sent in one go) to PC.

Now,if any command be sent after receiving the 4104 bytes,no response is seen.Only,after sending command twice I get response.

Can anyone guide to resolve this behavior of USB?

Answer (score 1):

> for in bulk transmission only 64 bytes can be sent in one go

Yes, and the connection will "hang" if your last transaction is *exactly* 64 bytes long. Reason is little known feature of bulk pipes that treats back-to-back 64 byte (max packet size) transactions as as single larger transaction. Any packet smaller than max packet size will finish a transaction.

A fix is simple: If you have no more bytes to transmit after a 64 byte packet, just transmit a *zero packet*. Yes, that is a packet containing no data bytes.

Most USB2UART example codes do not implement this fix, because the UART is usually not fast enough to fill the fifo to 64 bytes in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was on leave so could not revert back immediately. **Any packet smaller than max packet size will finish a transaction.**  So,yes, I send 64 packets in loop ,64 times plus the last 8 bytes in last packet.  **just transmit a zero packet. Yes, that is a packet containing no data bytes** . This would mean,  **USB_WriteEP (0x82, (unsigned char *)&Buffer[0], _0_ );**   ; right?

Comment: I tried zero length packet still it does not respond until the command is sent twice.

Comment: "Reason is little known feature of bulk pipes that treats back-to-back 64 byte (max packet size) transactions as as single larger transaction." I did not understand this part. Is it as per the USB specification? Is it a bulk pipe feature as per the USB specification? Please let me know the if you have reference to the specification about this limitation.

Comment: Its in the USB specs, see chapter 5.8.3 in the USB 2.0 spec.

Comment: The spec says its also over when the exact amount of data is transferred. Or smaller size packet too will end the transfer. As per OP, 8 bytes was the last packet size. That should have completed the transfer. But still it was hang. What do you think happened there? I believe it depends on the device too. Some devices make it mandatory to send zero length packet to end a transfer

Comment: @TurboJ - Now I verified what you said. Thanks a lot for clearing this thing. I needed to send a 0 length packet after sending all 512 byte packets for HS bulk transfer. Without sending 0 length packet, it was stuck.